# How to iterate from a given key in Java TreeMap

Tags: java, binary-search, treemap

I have a TreeMap, and want to get a set of K smallest keys (entries) larger than a given value.

I know we can use `higherKey(givenValue)` get the one key, but then how should I iterate from there?

One possible way is to get a `tailMap` from the smallest key larger than the given value, but that's an overkill if K is small compared with the map size.

Is there a better way with O(logn + K) time complexity?

Comment: Using `tailMap` is the correct solution. Note that constructing a tail map is a cheap operation, because it's just a view onto the original data. Think of it a little like an `Iterator`. Or put differently: **why** do you t hink that constructing a `tailMap` is overkill? What performance characteristics do you think it has?

Comment: @JoachimSauer I was thinking tailMap is O(n) but we only need O(k) if k << n (both time and space complexity). However if it's only a view, it might be different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error here is thinking that `tailMap` makes a new map. It doesn't. It gives you a lightweight object that basically just contains a field pointing back to the original map, and the pivot point, that's all it has. Any changes you make to a `tailMap` map will therefore also affect the underlying map, and any changes made to the underlying map will also affect your tailMap.

```
for (KeyType key : treeMap.tailMap(pivot).keySet()) {
}
```

The above **IS** `O(logn)` complexity for the `tailMap` operation, and give that you loop, that adds `K` to the lot, for a grand total of `O(logn+K)` time complexity, and O(1) space complexity, where N is the size of the map and K is the number of keys that end up being on the selected side of the pivot point (so, worst case, `O(nlogn)`).

If you want an actual copied-over map, you'd do something like:

```
TreeMap<KeyType> tm = new TreeMap<KeyType>(original.tailMap(pivot));
```

Note that this also copies over the used comparator, in case you specified a custom one. That one really is `O(logn + K)` in time complexity (and `O(K)` in space complexity). Of course, if you loop through this code, it's.. still `O(logn + K)` (because 2K just boils down to K when talking about big-O notation).